# How to make frames unresizable

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an "add task" button in my frame, which creates a new text widget to enter some text, with addition of text widgets the frame keeps expanding vertically

I've tried using resizable(False, False), it's showing
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'resizable'

```
class Container(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, priority = 3, bg = 'bisque'):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.f = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.f.configure(bg = bg)
        self.f.pack(fill = 'both', expand = True)
        self.tk.resizable(False, False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry('300x200-400+75')
    window.minsize(300, 600)

    p1 = Container(window, priority = 1)
    p2 = Container(window, bg = 'blue', priority = 2)
    p3 = Container(window, bg = 'red', priority = 3)

    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `self.tk.resizable(False, False)` for frame widget, it is only for the main window.

**Solution**

If you just want to make the frame not resizable when you add widgets to your frame use `self.propagate(0)` this will not let the children widgets to take over the size of the parent.

But If you want your main window not to resize then use `window.resizable(False, False)`

**Code**

```
import tkinter as tk

class Container(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, priority = 3, bg = 'bisque'):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.f = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.f.configure(bg = bg)
        self.propagate(0)
        self.f.pack(fill = 'both', expand = True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry('300x200+400+75')
    window.minsize(300, 600)

    # Use this if you don't want the main window to be resizable.
    # window.resizable(False, False)

    p1 = Container(window, priority = 1)
    p2 = Container(window, bg = 'blue', priority = 2)
    p3 = Container(window, bg = 'red', priority = 3)

    window.mainloop()
```